# Text justification in mla-paper package

Tags: horizontal-alignment

What command should I use to justify the entire text, both right and left, in mla-paper style package.

Comment: A [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) for sure will help to figure out a solution.

Comment: The style *does* justify the text. You may have a `\raggedright`, `\centering`, or `\raggedleft` command not protected by a group.

Comment: Note that MLA style explicitly forbids any justification and hyphenation. (Which kinda takes the fun out of LaTeX, but still.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Try to locate the place of a possibly existing `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft`, `\centering` or a command with similar effect. As egreg commented, protect it by a group, such as by curly braces or `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` or a LaTeX environment.
- If you don't find that place, you can still solve it by loading the [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package and using its command `\justifying`. This command switches back to justified text after ragged text has been switched on.